React Leaflet change scale of icon based on zoom
The goal is to have different sizes for markers based on the zoom level. While the following code works and changes the size of the marker the created div icon is remounted due to which the css transition of the scale is not working, but rather the marker just jumps to a bigger size.
divIcon is a lefatlet and not a react-leaftlet import, thus I believe we have an issue here as reconciliation isn't able to pick it up. When I create my own div and pass it as a child the entire placement of the custom icon gets messed up.
How can this be resolved that the markers smoothly change their size upon a zoom change?
<Marker
  icon={divIcon({
    html: `<div style="position:absolute; top:-25px; right:-7.5px; scale:${scale}; transition: 200ms scale;">
       <svg width="25" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <polyline points="12.5,5 ,20,17.5 20,45 5,45 5,17.5 12.5,5" fill="${props.carrier.color}" fill-opacity="0.4" stroke="${props.carrier.color}" stroke-width="1" />
       </svg>
   </div>`,
  })}
/>;


